# Android TableView and TextView as cell - how to setup TextView to be multiline

Tags: java, android, eclipse, textview

I have a TableView with TextView as cell elements. Currently I can't setup the layout file so that the TextView texts are multilined when the text width is wider than the cell width. It always end up with table cell growing width exceeding the screen width. How to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <TableLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:stretchColumns="*"
        android:id="@+id/tableLayout1">
        <TableRow android:id="@+id/tableRow1" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <TextView android:text="test1" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="0" />
            <TextView android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="test2 very long text that needs to be wrapped properly using layout_weight property and ignoring singleline since that is set by default..."
                android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        </TableRow>     
    </TableLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Set a fixed width to your TextView and everything should work...